# Connect 2 client for VideoCall over NAT in an Android App

Tags: java, android, p2p, voip, stun

I looked around for how to connect 2 client over NAT and all brought me to STUN.
I found a lot of API like jstun and ice4j but there is no documentation and examples.
Can someone help me?
Thank you all and sorry for my english.

**EDIT**
I found IcedJava that seems to be really good, it use the new RFC 5389 for STUN, ICE and TURN, but there is a really bad documentation for it. This one https://java.net/projects/siptools/pages/IcedJava
Someone knows a better documentation for it?